# Azure AD B2C ApiEndpoint confusion when deploying iOS app

Tags: azure, authentication, xamarin.forms, azure-ad-b2c

I am delving into authentication using B2C tenant in Azure for my app. I have kindly been pointed to the following github sample:

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native

The sample worked great out of the box, I could call the sample API using the ApiEndpoint:

```
public static string ApiEndpoint = "https://fabrikamb2chello.azurewebsites.net/hello";
```

What do I use as my own ApiEndpoint when deploying an iOS App using my own ADD tenant?

I have tried various permutations, I keep getting "hostname could not be found".

Many thanks.

Comment: You can ask your problem in https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home?forum=azuremobile

Comment: Hi Lucas. This is an MS sample. After reading extra MS docs, I posted my question in the issues on the Github repository for the sample (MS obviously), nothing. I called Azure sales, choice was watching videos or paying £800 per day to sort it via an MS Azure partner. After giving up with MS I came to my favorite place, Stack Overflow, where I am assured of quick, helpful, impartial advice. Clicked the link you gave me on my iPad & entered the problem there, except the textbox for entering a problem does not work (it's not there & shows error). Entered problem using my pc. Fingers crossed.